# Show that $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i -\hat{\mu}^\top)\cdot(x_i -\hat{\mu}^\top)^\top=E[(X-\hat{\mu})(X-\hat{\mu})^\top]$

Tags: mathematical-statistics, covariance, covariance-matrix

In a lecture my lecturer used the fact that $$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i -\hat{\mu}^\top)\cdot(x_i -\hat{\mu}^\top)^\top=E[(X-\hat{\mu})(X-\hat{\mu})^\top]$$where $X$ is our data matrix and $\hat{\mu}$ is the estimate of the mean vector. However I'm not sure how this follows. I tried expanding the left hand side and the right hand side but it does not seem to add up. Some help would be appreciated.

Comment: What would you think if you the lecturer had written $\frac1n \sum x_i = E(x)$? Could you figure out what the lecturer might mean in that case? and the lecturer’s lack of precision/clarity in using an equality...

Comment: The equality doesn't make sense as written, but $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i -\hat{\mu})(x_i -\hat{\mu})^\top$ can be an estimator of $E[(X-\mu)(X-\mu)^\top]$. Some context is needed.

Comment: The argument of "$E$" on the right hand side appears to be an $n\times n$ matrix of *numbers* whenever the data matrix $X$ has dimensions $n\times p.$  Please explain what "$E$" does to such a square matrix.  It's evidently not any kind of expectation!